# How to let some of the tasks in an airflow dag do not run, and the rest of the tasks run according to my input parameters?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have defined an airflow dag with certain numbers of different tasks, and all of these tasks are related to one parameter which is passed to the dag-define function. So when I pass different values to this parameter, I will get a different dag that has same task structure.

However, I come across a problem: How can I let some of these tasks not to run when I pass a certain parameter to the dag, and when I pass other parameters, all of these tasks should run normally.

For example, the dag code is like the following:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from libs.config.dag_config import Config
from etl.funcs import function1, function2, function3

def build_dag(id, schedule_interval):
    config = Config()
    config.add_params({'id': id,})
    with DAG(f'{id}_etl', default_args=config.default_args, schedule_interval=schedule_interval) as dag:
        start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
        end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')
        task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='task1',
                               python_callable=function1,
                               provide_context=True)
        task2 = PythonOperator(task_id='task2',
                               python_callable=function2,
                               provide_context=True)
        task3 = PythonOperator(task_id='task3',
                               python_callable=function3,
                               provide_context=True)
        tasks = [task1, task2, task3]
        start >> tasks >> end
        return dag

dag1 = build_dag(10001, '0 * * * *')
dag2 = build_dag(10002, '0 * * * *')
dag3 = build_dag(10003, '0 * * * *')
```

For dag1 and dag2, I want all the three tasks run normally, but for dag3, I only want to run the task1 and task2, and do not want to run task3. How to achieve this?

Comment: add Branch operators that will choose to what branch to follow based on your input.